# Can the extra conditional check at the call site be optimised out by the compiler easily?

Tags: c++, optimization

In the case where you need to check the return value at the call site, is it easy for the compiler to optimise it out if the value is checked in the function itself? Does it make a difference whether the function is inline? I tried looking at the assembly code to check for jumps but I'm afraid I don't understand it at all. I'm talking about a situation like this?

```
int* try_get()
{
    static int anint;
    anint = rand() % 2;
    if (anint) return &anint;
    else return nullptr;
    
}



int main()
{
    int* p = try_get();
    if (p) // The value was already tested in the function. 
// Is optimisation of this easy? Does it depend on whether the function is inline?
    {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. The function can return either a null pointer or a valid address, depending on the result of a call to `rand` ... how can the compiler know what that function will return at compile time? Note that the return value wasn't *tested* in the function - its value was *decided* by that function.

Comment: Which check in `try_get` should allow the `if(p)` to be optimized away? The `try_get` still returns either `nullptr` or not `nullptr`. Or are you asking if the compiler performs inlining for `try_get`, if it then could merge the two `if`?

Comment: @t.niese I mean merge the two ifs, it returns either null or a valid address, and then at the call site it checks if the result is null or not, but that's already been decided by the branch at if (anint)

Answer (score 1):

A C++ compiler is allowed to perform any optimization that has no observable effects, however the C++ standard does not require any C++ compiler to perform any such optimization (except those that are required by the C++ specification itself, such as [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)). Except for the required optimizations, everything else is entirely at your C++ compiler's discretion.

If the compiler has access both to the function definition and its call site, and the compiler can work out that this particular optimization has no observable effects, then the compiler can certainly optimize it out. Whether your compiler will do that can only be answered by looking at your compiler's compiled code. And even after determining what your compiler actually does will not, of course, bear any relevance to what any other compiler would do.

Whether or not the function in question is inline, or not, may or may not be a factor that your compiler considers when deciding whether to perform this optimization.

And, finally, even looking at what your compiler produced, for a particular translation unit, may not even paint the entire picture as well. Many current C++ compilers feature link-time optimizations, where the combined mighty forces of the compiler and the linker produce additional optimizations and code transformations in the final, linked executable.

So the only definitive answer here is to go actually look at the actual linked code in your final executable, in order to figure out whether any particular optimization took place, and, of course, that is a highly technical matter.

Comment: You might also mention that any change made (to code, tool-chain etc) many do or undo any observed optimisations.